# In Thor: Ragnarok , why doesn't Hela use a spaceship to get to other worlds instead of relying on the Bifrost

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-ragnarok

In Thor 3, why doesn't Hela use a spaceship to get to other worlds instead of relying on the Bifrost. To return to Asgard Thor and Friends used a spaceship. Did Asgard not have spaceships?

Comment: They didn't just use a spaceship though. They used a portal

Comment: Because the BiFrost is near instantaneous. Taking a spaceship from Xander to Asgard was said to be an 18 month journey (as an example of time wasted on a spaceship).

Comment: Even if they didn't normally have spaceships, there were probably a few crashed Dark Elf ships left over from *The Dark World* that they could repair and launch. Thor and Loki were able to get one working *without* any obvious repair work, so chances are the damage to the remaining ones is fairly light.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because it would take a long time to get anywhere.

When Thor is planning to leave Sakaar, Valkyrie begins to tell him how to get from there back to Asgard. Using her spaceship, she predicts the *fastest* they could get to Asgard is 18 months. The reason Thor and Loki manage to get back sooner is that Heimdal tells Thor the "big red one" is faster, but not every spaceship can make the journey.

The Bifrost, on the other hand, is instantaneous and can go anywhere directly point-to-point. Hela is clearly impatient and wants to go start conquering worlds *now*. On top of that, as a military weapon, its strategic use is immeasurable. She's not just angry because she can't travel off-world quickly, she's angry because Skurge lost one of her greatest assets.

(There are a few other ways to get to/from Asgard quickly, but they're not very convenient. Loki knows some secret, presumably magical, way but it's possible Hela doesn't know about it. Odin also managed to get Thor to Earth once but it took a lot of energy, and Hela may not be strong enough yet.)

Comment: What is "the big red one"?

Comment: @dean1957 the devil’s anus

Answer (score 8):

## The Bifrost is the only publicly-known way in and out of Asgard

This was a plot point in the Dark World, and possibly also Thor.

There is a hidden way that Loki knows, but it is well-hidden and there is no reason to think that Hela would be aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hela used some kind of teleportation for herself to come to earth the first time, when she broke Thor's hammer, but I think Bifrost is faster and easier to use when it comes to teleporting Hela's army.